# How to work with Word Document in the C# to transfer data to it?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I need that send may data to a word document.
I found a sample like this:

```
public class CCWordApp 
{
    private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass oWordApplic; // a reference to Word application
    private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oDoc;                    // a reference to the document


    public CCWordApp()
    {
        // activate the interface with the COM object of Microsoft Word
        oWordApplic = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
    }

    // Open a file (the file must exists) and activate it
    public void Open( string strFileName)
    {
        object fileName = strFileName;
        object readOnly = false;
        object isVisible = true;
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                    object bookmarkName="bookmarkname";
        oDoc = oWordApplic.Documents.Open(ref fileName)

        oDoc.Activate();

      if (oWordDoc.Bookmarks.Exists(bookmarkName.ToString())) 
        { 
          Bookmark bookmark = oWordDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref bookmarkName);
          bookmark.Range.Text="My Text";   
          bookmark.Select(); 
        } 

    }
}
```

this sample work correct but it depend that the file must exists.i store my word file in Database as byte[].how to i open my word file with this COM object?

Comment: r you want to open word file that you saved as byte[] in DB?

Comment: @WajidAli i save may word tamplate in DB.I want open it an fil its bookmarks

Comment: Why not save it as a temporary file somewhere?